# Undefined reference to static variable in c++

Tags: c++, static, rect

I'm trying to use a static variable in one of my classes. I've used them before, without problem. Now I'm getting this error:

> /tmp/ccg26aZi.o: In function 'main': main.cpp:(.text+0x7482):
>   undefined reference to `Rect::rect_change' collect2: error: ld
>   returned 1 exit status make: *** [exe] Error 1

any advice? Thanks!

UPDATE:

I was told to check my make file to make sure the rect.cpp was being included in the making of the exe. I switched the folder so it is in the correct place. But now I'm getting a whole new set of errors, I previously didn't get:

I checked my make file and made sure the rect.cpp, and moved it to a different folder that ran *.cpp. However Now I'm getting a brand new set of errors:

> > includes/Rect.h:16:17: error: ‘SDL_Rect’ does not name a type  Rect(const SDL_Rect & r)
> >
> > includes/Rect.h:16:28: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘r’ with no type [-fpermissive] Rect( const SDL_Rect & r)
>
> includes/Rect.h:19:2: error: ‘SDL_Rect’ does not name a type
>   SDL_Rect getSDL_Rect()   ^ includes/Rect.h: In constructor
>   ‘Rect::Rect(const int&)’: includes/Rect.h:17:9: error: request for
>   member ‘x’ in ‘r’, which is of non-class type ‘const int’ : x(r.x),
>   y(r.y), w(r.w), h(r.h)
>
> includes/Rect.h:17:17: error: request for member ‘y’ in ‘r’, which is
>   of non-class type ‘const int’    : x(r.x), y(r.y), w(r.w), h(r.h)
>
> includes/Rect.h:17:25: error: request for member ‘w’ in ‘r’, which is
>   of non-class type ‘const int’    : x(r.x), y(r.y), w(r.w), h(r.h)
>
> includes/Rect.h:17:33: error: request for member ‘h’ in ‘r’, which is
>   of non-class type ‘const int’    : x(r.x), y(r.y), w(r.w), h(r.h)

Here is the contents of my make file. the rect.cpp is located inside the src folder.

```
exe:    main.cpp
    g++ *.cpp src/*.cpp src/*.c `sdl-config --cflags --libs` -lSDL_image -lSDL_mixer -lSDL_ttf -Iincludes 

run:
    ./a.out

r:
    ./a.out

clean:
    rm a.out

c:
    rm a.out
```

---

```
// header
#ifndef RECT_H
#define RECT_H

#include <iostream>

class Rect
{
public:
    Rect(int x0 = 0, int y0 = 0, int w0 = 0, int h0 = 0)
        : x(x0), y(y0), w(w0), h(h0)
    {}
    Rect( const SDL_Rect & r)
        : x(r.x), y(r.y), w(r.w), h(r.h)
    {}
    SDL_Rect getSDL_Rect()
    {
        SDL_Rect r = {x, y, w, h};
        return r;
    }
    int x, y, w, h;
    static int rect_change;
    static int rect_change_max;
};

inline std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & cout, const Rect & r)
{
    cout << "(" << r.x << "," << r.y << "," << r.w << "," << r.h << ")";
    return cout;
}

#endif
```

---

```
rect.cpp    
#include "Rect.h"

int Rect::rect_change = 0;
int Rect::rect_change_max = 0;
```

---

```
   // main.cpp example
   #include "Rect.h"

   int main()
   {
       Rect rect;
       rect.rect_change = 5;

       return 0;
   }
```

Comment: It seems that you did not inlcude in the project file rect.cpp. Check you building of the project.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to include `rect.cpp` in creating the executable.

Comment: Can you include all of the commands you use to compile your software?

Comment: I'm in the same situation as the compiler: I cannot find a definition of `SDL_Rect`.

Comment: You have a mix of `SDL_Rect` and `Rect`. Is that on purpose?

Comment: Updated with all the info I can think of. Let me know if you guys need anything else. I appreciate all of the help. And to answer the above question: yes, that is on purpose. The rect code was given to me by my professor, and I'm trying to add static members to it (it was working before I added the static variables and tried to use them)

Comment: You need to include "SDL_rect.h" to get the definition of SDL_Rect.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, and thank you RichieHindle for the answer.

I needed to #include "SDL_gfxPrimitives.h" to get it to work. Funny that is the case because I've been working on this project for a while, and the compiler didn't complain at all, until I tried to add a static member.

Thanks again!